# I just watched at least 20 airplanes flying northeast over Washington, DC every 15-20 seconds, what were they?

Tags: military, usa, aircraft-identification

I just watched at least 20 airplanes flying northeast every 15-20 seconds over Washington, DC. They must have been military aircraft since flying very high. I just saw their lights (not blinking). They actually looked like satellites but I doubt so many in the same orbit every 15 seconds.  What is going on?

Answer (score 4):

This is very likely the "train" of satellites from Launch 5 of SpaceX's Starlink constellation. They have about that spacing at the moment, there are 60 of them, and the timing is about right. I saw them myself last night over Nevada.